# Disable exim4 logging

Tags: logging, exim

Currently exim4 logs to `/var/log/exim4/mainlog` but I would like to stop this.

I'v checked a few man pages but none show how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
log_selector = -all
```

in exim.conf, but I wouldn't really do that.
Complete list of valid values at http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch49.html#SECTlogselector

Comment: Why would you not do that?

Comment: 'cause I'd have no traces to analyze in case of problems (of any kind, from delivery to abuse...)